# How to generate dynamic paths for non-default locales in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, next.js, internationalization

I am building a Next.js app with internationalization using next-i18next. Pages are generated for all the pages of my site for both English and French, except for pages with dynamic routes: (i.e., `blog/[id]/[blog-title]`). For pages with dynamic routes, pages are generated for English, but not for French.

I should note that the blog entries are the same in both languages. So if the user click on a blog entry in the list, they will get the same blog entry.

When a French language user goes to a page with a dynamic route they get a 404. I am new to React and Next so I could be doing something dumb here.

```js
// next-i18next.config.js
module.exports = {
  i18n: {
    locales: ['en', 'fr'],
    defaultLocale: 'en',
    localeDetection: true,
  },
}
```

```js
//
// blog\[id]\[title] 
//
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const response = await axios.get('https://api.myappi.com/blog')
  const posts = response.data

  const paths = posts.map((post: Props) => ({
    params: { id: post.Id, title: post.Title },
  }))  
 
  return { paths, fallback: false }
}

export async function getStaticProps(props: IStaticProps) {
  const { id, locale } = props.params
  const response = await axios.get(`https://api.myappi.com/blog/${id}`)
  const post = await response.data

  if (!post) {
    return {
      notFound: true,
    }
  }

  return {
    props: { 
      Id: post.Id,
      Title: post.Title,
      Blog: post.Blog,
      DatePosted: post.DatePosted, 
      PostedBy: post.PostedBy,
      ...(await serverSideTranslations(props.locale, ['common', 'blog']))
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For dynamic routes, you have to explicitly return the locales you want to be pre-generated from the `getStaticPaths` function. If you don't, Next.js will only generate pages for the default locale.

From [Internationalized Routing](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing#dynamic-routes-and-getstaticprops-pages) documentation:

> For pages using `getStaticProps` with Dynamic Routes, all locale
> variants of the page desired to be prerendered need to be returned
> from `getStaticPaths`. Along with the `params` object returned for
> `paths`, you can also return a `locale` field specifying which locale
> you want to render.

This can be achieved by modifying your `getStaticPaths` function to generate a path for each slug/locale combination.

```js
export async function getStaticPaths({ locales }) { // Get available locales from `context`
   const response = await axios.get('https://api.myappi.com/blog')
   const posts = response.data

   const paths = posts
       .map((post: Props) => locales.map((locale) => ({
           params: { id: post.Id, title: post.Title },
           locale // Pass locale here
       })))
       .flat() // Flatten array to avoid nested arrays
 
   return { paths, fallback: false }
}
```

Comment: That did it. Thanks for this. I swear, I looked high and low in the docs for a solution. Obviously, I needed to look harder! Thanks again. 

Also, I will need to study up on flat(). That's a new one for me.