# Generating static pages routes with i18n and Strapi in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, fetch-api, strapi

I have a simple Next.js app that fetches data from Strapi. I use i18n in strapi and next. I have a page (/albums) that shows a list of albums. For each album I would like to generate a static page. It works fine for the default locale, but i'm unsure how to generate paths for each locale.

The app only uses two locales (en and fr).

Strapi generates an id for each album

```
Here is my [id].js page

import Layout from "../../components/layout";
import {getAlbumId, getAlbumData} from "../../libs/fetchAlbums";

export async function getStaticProps({ params}) {
    const albumData = await getAlbumData(params.id)
    return {
        props: {
            albumData
        }
    }
}

export async function getStaticPaths() {
    const paths =await getAlbumId()
    return {
        paths,
        fallback: false
    }
}

export default function AlbumDetails({albumData}){
    return(
        <Layout>
            {albumData.attributes.name}
        </Layout>
    )
}
```

and my fetchAlbums.js

```
import {useRouter} from "next/router";

export async function getAlbums({locale}){
    const fetchImages = await fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:1337/api/albums?locale=${locale}&populate=*`)
    const imageData = await fetchImages.json()
    return imageData.data
}

export async function getAlbumId(){

    const data = await getAlbums({locale: 'en'});
  

    return data.map((album) => {
        return {
            params : {
                id : album.id.toString(),
            }
        }
    })
}

export async function getAlbumData(id) {
    const album = await fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:1337/api/albums/${id}?populate=*&`)
    const albumData = await album.json()



    return {
        id,
        ...albumData.data
    }
}
```

I know the issue is in my getAlbumId() function. I think I should store both set of ids and have something like

````
const data = await getAlbums({locale: 'en'});
const dataFr = await getAlbums({locale: 'fr'});

const enIds = data.map((album) => {
    return album.id.toString()
})

const frIds = dataFr.map((album) => {
    return album.id.toString()
})```
````

But I'm confused at how I should structure my return params and what I should iterate since I would now have 2 set of ids

The behavior i'm expecting is that if for example there are 2 albums that are localized like :

```
id : 1 => album1 en
id : 2 => album1 fr
id : 3 => album2 en
id : 4 => album2 fr
```

I would get albums/1 and albums/3 and fr/albums/2 and fr/albums/4

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Next.js: Not all pages being generated for dynamic paths for non-default locales](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70626577/1870780)? `getStaticPaths` context object receives a `locales` property you can use to generate the localised paths.