# Implementing i18n with Dynamic Routing on NextJs

Tags: dynamic, routes, next.js, internationalization

I am implementing dynamic routing and i18n with Next.js. My app consists of 2 locales: `en-US` and `es-MX`. I am trying to generate the following routes:

- /blog/posts/[id]
- /es-MX/blog/posts/[id]

Using the default locale (`en-US`), my links point to `/blog/posts/id` and I am able to navigate to any id; for example: `/blog/posts/1` without any issue. However, when I switch locale, my links now point to the route `/es-MX/blog/posts/1`, which in turn result in a 404 error - not found.

My slug directory consists of the structure `pages/blog/posts/[id].js` and in this file I use `getStaticPaths` to generate the paths for the above locales:

```
export const getStaticPaths({locales}) => {
   const res = await fetch(`${server}/api/posts`);
   const posts = await res.json();

   const ids = posts.map((post) => post.id);
   const paths = ids.map((id) => ({
      params: {id: id.toString(), locale: 'en-US' },
      params: {id: id.toString(), locale: 'es-MX' },
   }));

   return {
       paths,
       fallback: false,
   };
}
```

I intend to pull post translations from the api according to the current locale. Everything else including all the other routes in the app work as expected, except this route. What am I missing?

Comment: The `locale` param needs to be passed outside the `params` object, i.e. `{ params: { id: id.toString() }, locale: 'es-MX' }`. See [How to generate dynamic paths for non-default locales in Next.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70596939/how-to-generate-dynamic-paths-for-non-default-locales-in-next-js).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the problem you're having there is you're returning `locale` inside `params` which is wrong, `locale` should be outside of `params` because it can be accessed through `context.locale` and not `context.params.locale`,
it worked for the `defaultLocale` because that's the default behavior of `getStaticPaths` with `locales`, read more on this [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing#dynamic-routes-and-getstaticprops-pages).

it's better if you rework your `getStaticPaths` like below to avoid problems with `params`:

```
export const getStaticPaths = async ({ locales }) => {
  const res = await fetch(`${server}/api/posts`);
  const posts = await res.json();

  const ids = posts.map((post) => post.id);
  const paths = ids
    .map((id) =>
      locales.map((locale) => ({
        params: { id: id.toString() },
        locale, //locale should not be inside `params`
      }))
    )
    .flat(); // to avoid nested arrays

  return {
    paths,
    fallback: false,
  };
};
```