# Strapi V4 & Next.js i18n dynamic routes getStaticPaths

Tags: javascript, next.js, internationalization, strapi

I'm trying to create a multilingual blog with Strapi v4 and Nextjs 18n using static routes with data from an api, with getStaticProps and getStaticPaths. When I make the request everything works correctly in the default language, the problem is when I change the language I can't display the information and I don't understand the reason, I have reviewed the documentation and I haven't been able to find the problem. If someone can guide me. Thanks in advance!

```
export async function getStaticPaths({ locales }) {
  
  const url = `${process.env.API_URL}/api/posts?populate=*`
  const response = await fetch(url);
  const posts= await response.json();
  const {data} = posts;
  
  const paths = locales.map((locale) => posts.map((post) => ({
    params: {posts: posts.id.toString(), locale: locale.toString()}
  }))).flat()

  return {
    paths,
    fallback: true,
  }
}

export async function getStaticProps({params:{id, locale}}) {


  const sortItems = `sort=rank`;
  const url = `${process.env.API_URL}/api/posts?filters[id][url][$eq]=${id}&${locale}&${sortItems}`;
  const response = await fetch(url);
  const posts = await response.json();

return {
  props: {
    posts
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: In the `paths` objects, the `locale` parameter needs to be outside the `params` object, i.e. `{ params: { posts: posts.id.toString() }, locale: locale.toString() }`. See [How to generate dynamic paths for non-default locales in Next.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70596939/how-to-generate-dynamic-paths-for-non-default-locales-in-next-js).